# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' while GridSearching CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/temp-frames/frames/train', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=256, class_mode='categorical')
validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/temp-frames/frames/validation', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=256, class_mode='categorical')
test_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/temp-frames/frames/test',target_size=(64,64),  batch_size=256, class_mode='categorical')

def create_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(filters= 128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation ='relu',strides = (2,2), padding = 'valid', input_shape= (64,64,3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(filters= 256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation ='relu',strides = (2,2), padding = 'valid'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(37)) 
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model


import sklearn
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
model = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_fn = create_model, verbose = 10)
​
batch_size_list = [10]
epochs = [10]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size_list, nb_epoch=epochs)
grid = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_dataset) # error here
```

I get an error at the last line:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`
```

How should I fix this? I was able to use `history = model.fit(train_dataset,batch_size = 2048, epochs = 100, validation_data = validation_dataset, shuffle = True)` without any problems previously.

Answer (score 0):

For supervised learning, the `.fit` method requires both `X` (input features) and `y` (true labels) arguments - check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit).

You must split your training dataset into inputs and labels and feed both to `grid.fit`.

Comment: I was able to train a previous CNN using "history = model.fit(train_dataset,batch_size = 2048, epochs = 100, validation_data = validation_dataset, shuffle = True)" where I did not have any labels

Comment: `model.fit` is just fitting the Keras model which could be supervised or otherwise. `GridSearchCV` is specifically for supervised problems.

Comment: *where I did not have any labels* it should be because your train dataset was made by TF-Dataset API @AllenYe

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I will try splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` works as any scikit-learn estimator,
so need a `y` argument for Neural Networks - see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

So you should divide `train_dataset` into two separate datasets (best is DataFrame) of dimensions [n, m-p] and [n, p].

Comment: What is n, m, and p? Should I use the train_dataset or the test_dataset for the Dataframe

Comment: n: number of rows, m : initial number of columns, p: dimension of target class,
In a very simple dataset:
dataset: [feature1, feature2, target1]  m=3, p=2,    so X =[:, [feature1, feature2]], y=[:, [target1]]

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out.